# What makes a microcontroller development board powerful?

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, board, development, robot

I'm seeing an awful lot of dev boards on the internet that arent Raspberry Pis or Arduinos and I'd like to know what makes a board powerful? Whats the difference between a board that may be used in a factory to control many robotic arms and a Raspberry Pi that can control just one arm?

Comment: Primarily what microcontroller it uses, but if you're concerned about how many things you can control, number of inputs and outputs may be of note.

Comment: *what makes a board powerful* What **is** powerful? Powerful is a relative term. The ATMega microcontroller is powerful if you use it in a coffee maker but it is not if you try to use it for face recognition.

Comment: Onboard peripherals to implement in hardware interfaces you need for your product and enough pins and Flash to actually do it.  USART, SPI, I2C, CAN, ethernet, Counters/Timers, PWM, A/D, D/A, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just punched "uC dev board" into the google, clicked the first link, for a "Teensy 3.2" and found the following under features.  Note that every feature matters and there are many things to consider that won't appear on a marketing "feature" list, so you'll have to learn what each thing does and how to figure out what you need for a given application.

- 32 bit ARM Cortex-M4 72 MHz CPU (M4 = DSP extensions)

Ze processor.  This does the actual computation, so  your calculation/decision load will determine how much processing power you need per core and the degree to which multiple cores are useful.

- 256K Flash Memory, 64K RAM, 2K EEPROM

Flash memory to store information when powered down, RAM(unspecified here, but specs are relevant) for fast memory, and EEPROM for semipermanent memory.

- 21 High Resolution Analog Inputs (13 bits usable, 16 bit hardware)

Pretty self explanatory, but note that the "13 bits usable" will determine resolution.

- 34 Digital I/O Pins (5V tolerance on Digital Inputs)

Just a ridiculous number of I/O pins for a weakish processor.  I don't usually look at these things, but suffice to say you could directly control 34 individual switches with these, use one or more for communication, or run I\$^2\$C busses, whatever your processor can keep up with, in addition to its intended processing load.  Dedicated ports are better for communication.

- 12 PWM outputs

These are useful as once they are set up, they operate without a great burden on the processor.  Processor sets frequency and duty cycle according to instruction, and they will maintain that output without eating cycles.

- 7 Timers for intervals/delays, separate from PWM

Exactly what it sounds like, possibly set up in the same way as the PWM outs, to reduce processor load and/or the need for interrupts, although I'm not sure of that.  I'm guessing they mention "separate from PWM" because the PWM drivers are astable multivibrators and these are monostable multivibrators, so maybe on some chips they are multi purposed and conflict with each other.

- USB with dedicated DMA memory transfers

Exactly what it sounds like, If security is relevant in your application, your ears should probably perk up when you see "DMA" and know there's something  you should check.

- 3 UARTs (serial ports)

3 really flexible serial communication ports

- SPI, I2C, I2S, CAN Bus, IR modulator

It appears there is a built in modulator for these communication standards

- I2S (for high quality audio interface)

They're so excited about the I\$^2\$S, they mention it twice.  Serial audio interface.

- Real Time Clock (with user-added 32.768 crystal and battery)

The machine can tell time!  Roughly as well as a quartz watch.  You'll have to add the crystal if you want this functionality.

- 16 DMA channels (separate from USB)

DMA matters less here because these channels would normally be used by you for interconnects, with no USB cable/bus involved.

- Touch Sensor Inputs

You can use (I assume specifically capacitive) touch sensors with this board with little effort.

- 1.4 x 0.7" (~35 x 18 mm)

That's probably why it's named an ATTiny.  So small.  Note if you were looking for a board with a screen, you should probably check resolution/refresh rate.

So now you know roughly the features of this randomly selected board, but still have no idea if it's any use to you.  You have to look at your intended function.  Robot Arms as an example?  You don't start by looking at processors, you start by looking at your application.  Be methodical.  How many arms?  How many motors per arm.  You'll have to figure out roughly how much communication and processing power is necessary for the arms to operate, so before you do that you'll need to figure out how fast that is.

If you're a beginner and you just want to find your first dev board and controlling robotic arms is specifically of interest to you, just find an overpowered practice board to experiment with or copy someone else's design.  You can also use a better-than-necessary board/processor to execute your application and test how much processing power you need, rather than learning the engineering skills to predict.

In short, every feature that a given board has matters, in that unnecessary components are a burden and you also must be sure to have everything you need, so work backwards from your goal or empirically determine the necessary specs.

As a final note, because you mention specifically a "Factory", one thing that will make the Programmable Logic Controllers and Variable Frequency Drives, as well as other processors in a factory (in a factory a single robotic arm may have multiple processors) is the degree to which they're protected.  Optoisolators are used to protect inputs from surges/spikes/misconnection.  If you're building a smallish arm at home, this certainly wouldn't be necessary.

Hope this helps.